# Rails: How can I use system zip on Heroku to make a docx from an xml template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, zip, docx

I have this working locally, storing the template files in `#{Rails.root}/tmp`, using `system "cd tmp/template; zip -r ../#{@filename} *"` to zip up the files, sending the .docx (zip archive) to S3 and then to the browser. The problem is that Heroku is not finding the files. Before I create the xml file, I am copying the template directory from another location (`system "cp -R support/ser_template tmp/"`). I understand Heroku's [read-only filesystem](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) but I can't have `#{Process.pid}`'s littering my filenames (Word requires the xml file to be named document.xml).

Is there anyway I can store the template files on Amazon and still use Heroku's system zip utility? [RubyZip does not create proper docx archives](http://tomasvarsavsky.com/2009/04/04/simple-word-document-templating-using-ruby-and-xml/).

Edit: here is the code:

```
require 'aws/s3'

class WordDocument
  include ConnectS3

  def initialize(content)
    connect_s3
    @pid = Process.pid
    @filename = "SER_" + Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + '.docx'
    system "cp -R #{Rails.root}/support/ser_template #{temp_path}"
    xml = File.open(xml_path, 'w')
    xml.puts content
    xml.close
    system "cd #{temp_path}; zip -r #{@filename} *"
    docx = File.open(temp_path + "/" + @filename, 'r')
    AWS::S3::S3Object.store(s3_path, docx, @s3_credentials["bucket"], :use_virtual_directories => true)
    AWS::S3::S3Object.grant_torrent_access_to s3_path, @s3_credentials["bucket"]
  end

  def temp_path
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@pid}_ser"
  end

  def xml_path
    temp_path + "/word/document.xml"
  end

  def path
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/" + @s3_credentials["bucket"] + s3_path
  end

  def s3_path
    '/section_editor_reports/' + @filename
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just a create directory within `#{Rails.root}/tmp` called, say, `#{Process.pid}_docx/something_nice/`? Copy (or symlink) what you need into:

```
#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{Process.pid}_docx/something_nice/
```

Then

```
system "cd #{Rails.root}/tmp/#{Process.pid}_docx/; zip -r x.zip something_nice"
```

And then you have:

```
#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{Process.pid}_docx/x.zip
```

With a nice pretty internal structure that doesn't include your PID.

Comment: I still get `Errno::ENOENT` `No such file or directory - /app/tmp/1_ser/word/document.xml`

Comment: Heroku. I've now tried it on 3 different stacks (bamboo 1.8.7, bamboo 1.9.2, and Cedar). I get `No such file or directory` on all but bamboo 1.9.2 where I get `Permission denied - /app/tmp/1_ser/word/document.xml`

Comment: @Reed: Are you creating the directory in one process but trying to access it in another? Is it the copying or the zipping that complains?

Comment: I'm creating and zipping the files in one process (a user requests a Word export and an xml template is generated from a view using `render_to_string`). I'm getting the error on this line: `xml = File.open(xml_path, 'w')`

Comment: @Reed: Have you checked the permissions on the directory you made or what your umask is on Heroku?

Comment: `umask` in the console returns `nil`. The permissions on the `tmp` directory are `drwx------  4 u14017 14017 4.0K Jun 28 18:44 tmp\ `

Comment: @Reed: What about the permissions on the files and directories that you just copied over? You might want to use `cpio` to copy the files but that's another issue.

Comment: They are `dr-xr-x---  5 root 24129 4.0K Jun 28 18:08 ser_template` and I tried `xml = File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/1_ser/word/document.xml", 'w')` on the console but got permission denied.

Comment: @Reed: Can you [`File.chmod`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000010) the directories and files? 0755 for the directories and 0644 for the files should be good.

Comment: I had this error - Heroku likes to add 'app/' to the temp path which is incorrect. You want './tmp' not './app/tmp'. Here's a fix: `rails_root = Rails.root.to_s.gsub('/app','')`