# Run ruby-debug on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, heroku, ruby-debug

Is there any way to do it? I often have issues that work locally but fail on Heroku for some reason related to the environment. It would be nice to be able to run the debugger there.

Comment: Yes, it's when there's a unique issue such as with the filesystem when I really want to use the debugger.

Comment: you can't write to the filesystem in heroku (except with /tmp but I don't remember right now exactly), can we see the code?

Comment: It's related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417475/rails-how-can-i-use-system-zip-on-heroku-to-make-a-docx-from-an-xml-template

Comment: I doubt this would be possible. Sounds like a good idea though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently apps do not have interactive debugging on Heroku. You do have access to the logger, however.

**References**

- See Heroku's docs on [Writing to Your Log](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing_to_your_log) and [Log Retrieval](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log_retrieval).